# Can this SQL Query be improved

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, query-performance

Related to one of my previous questions: [How to select a subset from a query result](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127349/how-to-select-a-subset-from-a-query-result)

I now have this Query:

```
CREATE TABLE #JourneyLogs
    (
        JourneyStartId INT,
        JourneyEndId INT,
        AssetId INT,
        [Event] INT,
        JourneyStart DATETIME,
        JourneyEnd DATETIME,
        GeofenceId INT,
        JourneyDistanceKM FLOAT,
        JourneyTime INT
    )

    INSERT INTO #JourneyLogs
        SELECT 
              JourneyStartId
            , JourneyEndId
            , AssetId
            , [Event]
            , JourneyStart
            , JourneyEnd
            , GeofenceId
            , JourneyDistance = ROUND((SUM(DistanceCoveredK) / 1000), 3, 1)
            , JourneyTime
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                 JourneyStartId = ignOn.iVehicleMonitoringId
                ,JourneyEndId = ignOff.iVehicleMonitoringId
                ,AssetId = ignOn.iAssetId
                ,JourneyStart = DATEADD(hour, @fGmtOffSet, ignOn.dtUTCDateTime) 
                ,JourneyEnd = DATEADD(hour, @fGmtOffSet, ignOff.dtUTCDateTime)
                ,[Event] = ignOff.eEventCode
                ,DistanceCoveredK = p.sptGeoLocaitonPoint.STDistance(
                                        LEAD(p.sptGeoLocaitonPoint) OVER(PARTITION BY ignOn.iAssetId, ignOn.dtUTCDateTime ORDER BY ignOff.dtUTCDateTime))
                ,GeofenceId = ignOn.iGeofenceId
                ,JourneyTime = DATEDIFF(SECOND, ignOn.dtUTCDateTime, ignOff.dtUTCDateTime)
            FROM VehicleMonitoringLog ignOn
            CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT top(1) iVehicleMonitoringId, eEventCode, dtUTCDateTime, sptGeoLocaitonPoint 
                FROM VehicleMonitoringLog WHERE 
                iAssetId = ignOn.iAssetId AND dtUTCDateTime > ignOn.dtUTCDateTime AND eEventCode = 2
                ORDER by dtUTCDateTime
            ) ignOff
            INNER JOIN VehicleMonitoringLog p ON p.iAssetId = ignOn.iAssetId AND p.dtUTCDateTime >= ignOn.dtUTCDateTime AND p.dtUTCDateTime <= ignOff.dtUTCDateTime
            WHERE 
                ignOn.dtUTCDateTime > @utcStartDate AND ignOn.dtUTCDateTime < @utcEndDate
                AND ignOn.iAssetId in (Select iAssetId FROM #tblAssets)
                AND ignOn.eEventCode = 1
        ) g

        GROUP BY AssetId, [Event], GeofenceId, JourneyStart, JourneyEnd, JourneyTime, JourneyStartId, JourneyEndId
```

This takes 19 seconds and returns 4830 rows, with STATISTICS IO:

```
Table '#JourneyLogs________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000148'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4864, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 146540, logical reads 857406, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'VehicleMonitoringLog'. Scan count 9719, logical reads 64578, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#tblAssets__________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000147'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(4830 row(s) affected)
```

Execution Plan: [Here](https://gist.github.com/mdawood1991/c7e5bb2191e976d5e839)

Is there a way to improve this query?

Comment: @Molenpad VehicleMonitoringLog  is a Table with Clustured Index on iAssetId amd dtUtcDateTime

Comment: Why is degree of parallelism 1?

Comment: Have you run it through DTA?

Comment: @stacylaray, DOP is probably 1 because the query has an estimated cost of only 20. I would not recommend anyone to use DTA, but rather focus on tuning the query and/or indexes.

Comment: @stacylaray, also, I think CLR datatypes, like the geography datatype will force MAXDOP=1, though I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, these are the improvements I would try:

- Add a clustered (unique if possible) index to the temp table, `#tblAssets (iAssetId)`. This will eliminate the Sort operator, and may potentially improve the type of join operator.
- On the index `IX_VehicleMonitoringLog_iAssetId_eEventCode_NonClustered`, include the column `iVehicleMonitoringId`. This will eliminate the KeyLookup operator, which is potentially very expensive.

Not so much an optimization, but rather for correctness: Shouldn't this...

`PARTITION BY ignOn.iAssetId, ignOn.dtUTCDateTime ORDER BY ignOff.dtUTCDateTime`

... rather be...

`PARTITION BY ignOn.iAssetId, ignOn.dtUTCDateTime ORDER BY p.dtUTCDateTime`?

I'm thinking that for all the records of any given partition, the `ignOff.dtUTCDateTime` should be the same, and you probably want to loop through each "segment", i.e. the `p.dtUTCDateTime`, right?

You may already get the correct results by accident with the current query because the records may be correctly ordered from the Index Seek on `p`, but I would probably want to make sure by specifying the correct ordering. As a bonus, this might improve performance.